# How to run a Tasker command from a Android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, tasker

I see that apps like Nova Launcher, Trigger and etc have an option to run Tasker tasks. Instead of creating an app with Tasker App Factory, I want to know how to implement an Intent that runs a Tasker task.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just found by myself in Tasker Developer Information:
http://tasker.dinglisch.net/developers.html